# How does the key argument in python's sorted function work?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

Say I have

```
votes = {'Charlie': 20, 'Able': 10, 'Baker': 20, 'Dog': 15}
```

I understand

```
print(sorted(votes.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]))
```

will lead to

```
[('Able', 10), ('Dog', 15), ('Baker', 20), ('Charlie', 20)]
```

But how does this work?

Comment: I see, thanks, so what if I changed the key to return a tuple though? What's happening there? 

`key = lambda x: (-x[1],x[0])`

Comment: That would sort by the tuples `(-value, key)`. It would end up sorting by the values from greatest to least, and breaking ties with the keys. The result would be `[('Baker', 20), ('Charlie', 20), ('Dog', 15), ('Able', 10)]`.

Comment: Oh ok, so what's the purpose of having the `x[0]` key aspect in the tuple if it's ignored by the sort? I guess I mean, why would I want to return a tuple there in the lambda?

Comment: The `x[0]` is not ignored; it's used to break ties with the first item in the tuple. That's why `('Baker', 20)` will always come before `('Charlie', 20)`

Comment: So since they have the same value, the `x[0]` allows those with equivalent values to be sorted by their key? And I'm sorry I don't quite know what you mean by "break ties with the keys"

Comment: When sorting tuples, Python first sorts by the first value. Then, if there are any ties (i.e. two or more tuples have the same first value), it sorts by the second value, then the third if there are any ties in the second value, etc. Think of it like sorting words in alphabetical order. First you sort by the first letter; if there are any ties, you sort by the second letter; you keep going until there are no more ties, or you run out of letters.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The function you pass in to `key` is given each of the items that are being sorted, and returns a "key" that Python can sort by. So, if you want to sort a list of strings by the *reverse* of the string, you could do this:

```
list_of_strings.sort(key=lambda s: s[::-1])
```

This lets you specify the value each item is sorted by, without having to change the item. That way, you don't have to build a list of reversed strings, sort that, then reverse them back.

```
# DON'T do this

data = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl']
reversed_data = [s[::-1] for s in data]
reversed_data.sort()
data = [s[::-1] for s in reversed_data]

# Do this

data.sort(key=lambda s: s[::-1])
```

In your case, the code is sorting each item by the *second* item in the tuple, whereas normally it would initially sort by the first item in the tuple, then break ties with the second item.

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> votes = {'Charlie': 20, 'Able': 10, 'Baker': 20, 'Dog': 15}
```

If we apply `.items()` on the `votes` dictionary above we get:

```
>>> votes_items=votes.items()
>>> votes_items
[('Charlie', 20), ('Baker', 20), ('Able', 10), ('Dog', 15)]
#a list of tuples, each tuple having two items indexed 0 and 1
```

For each tuple, the first index `[0]` are the strings (`'Charlie','Able','Baker','Dog'`) and the second index `[1]` the integers (`20,10,20,15`).

`print(sorted(votes.items(), key = lambda x: x[1]))` instructs python to sort the items`(tuples)` in `votes` using the second index `[1]` of each tuple, the integers, as the basis of the sorting.

Python compares each integer from each tuple and returns a list that has ranked each tuple in ascending order (this can be reversed with the `reverse=True` argument) using each tuple's integer as the `key` to determine the tuple's rank,

Where there is a tie in the key, the items are ranked in the order they are originally in the dictionary. (so `('Charlie', 20)` is before `('Baker', 20)` because there is a `20==20` tie on the key but ('`Charlie', 20)` comes before `('Baker', 20)` in the original `votes` dictionary).

The output then is:

```
 [('Able', 10), ('Dog', 15), ('Charlie', 20), ('Baker', 20)]
```

I hope this makes it easier to understand.

Answer (score 3):

key is a function that will be called to transform the collection's items before they are compared. The parameter passed to key must be something that is callable.

The use of lambda creates an anonymous function (which is callable). In the case of sorted the callable only takes one parameters. Python's lambda is pretty simple. It can only do and return one thing really.

Answer (score 3):

The `key` parameter takes a function as its value, which is applied to each element before sorting, so that the elements are sorted based on the output of this function.

For example if you want to sort a list of strings based on their length, you can do something like this:

```
    list = ['aaaaaa', 'bb', 'ccc', 'd']
    sorted(list, key=len)

    # ['d', 'bb', 'ccc', 'aaaaaa']
```