# How does `key=function` in `sorted(tuple, key=function)` work?

Tags: python, sorting, tuples

> Given a list of non-empty tuples, return a list sorted in increasing order by the last element in each tuple.
>
> e.g. [(1, 7), (1, 3), (3, 4, 5), (2, 2)] yields [(2, 2), (1, 3), (3, 4, 5), (1, 7)]
>
> Hint: use a custom key= function to extract the last element form each tuple.

The solution to the problem is:

```
def last(a): 
   return a[-1]
def sort_last(tuples):  
   return sorted(tuples, key=last)
```

Can anyone help me to understand what arguments are passed to the `last` function? Specifically, what does `a` contain?

We have not passed any values or arguments while calling the `last` function in the `sorted` method.

Comment: *You* didn't call `last()` at all.  `sorted()` is the one calling that function, and does so once for each element of the sequence passed to it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the key argument in python's sorted function work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32238196/how-does-the-key-argument-in-pythons-sorted-function-work)

Answer (score 1):

This is what is called a "lambda".

It's passing the current element of your list to the function "last" which will then get the last element of the tuple.

So the parameter "a" is the tuple being currently processed.

Comment: This is not a lambda. Lambdas say `lambda` at the front. We're passing a named function as the `key` here.

Comment: It's using a value from a list being processed by the sorted function. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus It's a variation of a lambda.

Comment: Not relevant. Lambdas are a specific syntactical construct for creating functions; whether a function is a lambda or not has nothing to do with how the function is used.

Comment: @crey4fun Thank you for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Iterating through a tuple via for loop - (Sorted initial list with 2nd element of the tuple.) 
Nested for loops - comparing original tuple with the sorted 2nd element list.

```py
tuple1 = [(2, 5), (1, 2), (4, 4), (2, 3), (2, 1)]

List2 =[]
List3 =[]

for t in tuple1:
    List2.append(t[1],)

List2.sort()
print(List2)

for l in List2:
    for q in tuple1:
        if l == int(q[1],):
            List3.append(q)

print(List3)
```

Comment: Hi user13557829, please read up on [writing a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Enjoy your stay here at SO :)