# Accumulate values in a list of tupelets [python]

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I have a list of the following tupelets (all in the same format) which I have generated by querying a database:

```
('topic1', 'Will', 5),
('topic1', 'John', 120),
('topic1', 'John', 15),
('topic8378', 'John', 1),
('topic8378', 'Will', 10),
('topic8378', 'John', 10),
('topic8378', 'Jessica', 5),
('topic8378', 'Will', 1),
('topic15', 'Will', 1),
('topic15', 'John', 1),
('topic15', 'Will', 1),
('topic15', 'Will', 1),
('topic15', 'John', 1),
('topic15', 'John', 1),
('blah10', 'Jessica', 8),
('blah10', 'John', 18),
```

The third value of these dictionaries is an 'amount' field.  I want to accumulate a new list of tupelets by adding total amounts for each person in each topic, so that it (for example) returns a simplified total list per topic (reverse sorted in a list):

```
('topic1', 'John', 135)
('topic1', 'Will', 10)
('topic8378', 'John', 11)
('topic8378', 'Will', 10)
('topic8378', 'Jessica', 5)
('topic15', 'Will', 3)
('topic15', 'John', 3)
('blah10', 'John', 18)
('blah10', 'Jessica, 8)
```

Should I use itemgetter in this scenario?  What is the best way to cross-check duplicates and accumulate totals for the middle field?

Comment: The question was marked as duplicate before I could post my answer. Here is a PasteBin with a solution using `itertools.groupby` for your case: https://pastebin.com/3CxCPAtK

Comment: I'm confused, you used key_topic_name as a function, but in this line:
sorted_tuple_list = sorted(tuple_list, key=key_topic_name)
You used it as a variable with no arguments?

Comment: `key_topic_name()` is indeed a function, and we are passing it as argument to `sorted()` and `groupby()` as the `key` argument. In Python, everything is an object, and we can pass functions as arguments to other functions. If you want more details about `key`, feel free to check out this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32238222/7663649).

Comment: It works perfectly.  Sorry about the duplicate question - kudos, mate.  I was using nested for loops and it just wasn't working out.

Comment: You're welcome, I hope my late answer was helpful!