# How does sorted() work for lists inside of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am confused on how lists inside lists get sorted.

```
L = [[1,1,1],[0,9,0],[2,1,1]]
```

`sorted(L)` returns `[[0, 9, 0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 1, 1]]`

This means that it is not based off sum as 0+9+0 is larger than both of the other ones.

Comment: Is the first element's `0, 1, 2` such an illogical order?

Comment: if you want to sort based on the sum, you need to tell it to do so: `sorted(L, key=sum)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the key argument in python's sorted function work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32238196/how-does-the-key-argument-in-pythons-sorted-function-work)

Comment: It sorts lexicographically. If the first elements of two sublists are equal, then the second elements are compared, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

No it is based on all the elements of the iterator starting from the first element of the iterator

```
sorted(L,key=lambda x:(x[0],x[1],x[2]) #==sorted(L)
```

In case you need by sum

```
sorted(L,key=sum)
```

A more simplified version of above code to understand the key argument further

```
print(sorted(L,key=lambda x: x[0]+x[1]+x[2]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Built-in `sorted` considers **each element of an iterable in turn**. So, for example, `[0, 9, 0]` appears first because `0 < 1` and `0 < 2`.

To help gain intuition, you can test a few examples:

```
[0,9,0] < [1,1,1]  # True
[0,9,0] < [0,8,0]  # False
[1,1,1] < [2,1,1]  # True
```

So `sorted` works consistently with how comparison operators are defined. Sequence objects in Python usually support [lexicographic comparison](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types). To sort by the sum of each list, you need to feed a function to the `key` argument, in this case built-in `sum`:

```
res = sorted(L, key=sum)
```